# How do I Rewrite URL from some-sub-domain.some-domain.com to some-domain.com/some-sub-domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URL, so that I can reach the folder which is seen by the clients as sub-domain. Client will put the following in the URL Bar:

```
abc.def.com
```

and by URL rewrite it will be gone to

```
def.com/abc
```

silently. Please tell me how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very few change in your RewriteRule to work this well

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\.your_domain\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

You should use $ in the RewriteRule. Hope this helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead of `%{REMOTE_HOST}`. This is because `%{REMOTE_HOST}` is the result of reverse DNS lookup on `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` if `HostnameLookups` is enabled.

So your rule should be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\.your_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the subdomain, you can:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?subdomain\.your_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /subdomain/$1 [L]
```

And if you wish to support ANY possible subdomain, use:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^\.]+)\.your_domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry for say, but does not work for me. For your information when I use the subdomain it lands nowhere. Browser says that server not found.

Comment: Then you need to add the subdomain to your DNS. The above assumes the subdomain is reachable and points to the webserver running mod_rewrite.

Comment: mod_rewrite is enable in my web server. If I use wildcard (*) sub-domain no result yet then. What should I do ?

Comment: Without further information about your setup, I'm afraid I cannot help. What is the domain of your webserver and the subdomain you want to serve?